# Count if data is higher than another series within a rolling window of past two (or more) values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, window-functions, rolling-computation

I have this two Series in a DataFrame:

```
A    B
1    2
2    3
2    1
4    3
5    2
```

and I would to create a new column `df['C`] that counts how many times the value in column `df['A']`is higher than the value in column `df['B']` for a rolling window of the previous 2 (or more) rows.

The result would be something like this:

```
    A    B   C
    1    2   NaN
    2    3   NaN   
    2    1   0
    4    3   1
    5    2   2
```

I would also like to create a column that sums the data in `df['A']` higher than `df['B']` always using a rolling window.

With the following result:

```
    A    B   C    D
    1    2   NaN  NaN
    2    3   NaN  NaN
    2    1   0    0
    4    3   1    2
    5    2   2    6
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df.assign(C=df.A.gt(df.B).rolling(2).sum().shift(),D=(df.A.gt(df.B)*df.A).rolling(2).sum().shift())
Out[1267]: 
   A  B    C    D
0  1  2  NaN  NaN
1  2  3  NaN  NaN
2  2  1  0.0  0.0
3  4  3  1.0  2.0
4  5  2  2.0  6.0
```